# Can I remove /etc/php/5.6 after I purged php5.6-common?

Tags: 16.04

I tried to install the php5.6 besides php7.0 of the ondrej repository on my Ubuntu Root-Server Version 16.04.

Both PHP-Versions doesn't work for me like expected and I decide to deinstall that ondrej php5.6 package. After some weeks I found an entry in my `var/mail/root` file, where some lines like this was:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I searched askubuntu and found this:

```
apt list --installed
```

In the following list I found that lines:

```
php5.6-cli/now 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php5.6-common/now 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php5.6-json/now 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php5.6-opcache/now 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
php5.6-readline/now 5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,local]
```

It tells me that my deinstallation doesn't work, so i askubuntu again ;)

With

```
apt-get purge php5.6-common
```

the 5 lines was no more found in `apt list --installed`. And the folder `/usr/lib/php/20131226` was also removed.

But I got those Error messages:

```
Purging configuration files for php5.6-cli (5.6.33- 
3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

dpkg: warning: while removing php5.6-cli, directory 
'/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d' not empty so not removed
```

and

```
Purging configuration files for php5.6-common (5.6.33- 
3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

dpkg: warning: while removing php5.6-common, directory '/etc/php/5.6/mods- 
available' not empty so not removed
```

My question is: Can I delete `/etc/php/5.6` folder with `rm -r 5.6` or do I getting errors then?